# How do I use PostgreSQL inet Operators like '<<' with the Hibernate Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Given a CIDR string like '192.168/16', I would like to check that an IP Address in my PostgreSQL table is contained within it.

The SQL I would write would be along the lines of:

`SELECT ip 
  FROM ip_mac
 WHERE ip << inet('192.168/16');`

Our application uses Hibernate. I already have a UserType defined to convert Strings to an Inet type. I need to be able to use the `<<` and others when querying for IP addresses.

1. How do I get Hibernate to render the `<<` operator?
2. How do I get Hibernate to render `inet(CIDR_STRING)`?

I would like to be able to use the Criteria API to do this as other criteria could be part of the query too. I have seen [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2444287), but the solution involved using a native JPA query and a cast. I would prefer to stick with Java semantics where possible.

Comment: You cannot use those in HQL or Criteria. Try using a native query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing my own answer. The comment made by @Sotirios Delimanolis is correct: what I wanted was not possible with either HQL or Criteria. We resorted to a PostgreSQL-specific native SQL query. This serves our purpose for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a custom Hibernate Criterion can be created that will address this, allowing the use of the Criteria API and avoiding raw SQL or HQL. If you're already using Criteria for other selectors, this is the way to go.